# Programmatically validate a node?

Tags: 6, forms, nodes

I am programmatically creating many nodes. Obviously they have to be valid before storing them. Such `$node` objects have CCK fields mixed with custom fields.

Because the validators only set a [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) and hardly ever return the validation-result, I have to go trough the form-api in order to know if a node is valid, or so it seems.

I call [`node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_validate/6), then [`form_get_errors()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_get_errors/6) (which, in turn calls `form_set_error()`).

There appear to be several problems with this approach:

- `form_set_error()` sets a message with [`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6); for stuff like cron (a session-less user), this adds orphaned persistent error-messages to the database (they will never be printed, hence never deleted).
- the returning array of errors is created to be used in a multidimensional form array. Especially with CCK-fields, I have to dig quite deep in order to find the actual error.
- I just want to store a node, so I am not interested in a user-faced form; using the form API just feels wrong.

Is there a simpler, more elegant method?

Comment: Is the problem that your data source that you are using may have invalid data in it, or just that you are trying to validate your own code?

Comment: I just want to avoid storing nodes that are "invalid", according to whatever defines if they are valid. If, say, an image is required, one can assume that the theme will be able to render that image, regardless. If my importers start saving nodes without these images, the theme will print broken image-links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any other ways, as the hooks that the modules need to implement to validate a node are `hook_validate()` (if the module implements a content type) and [hook_nodeapi('validate')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (for all the other modules). Those hooks get a `$form` parameter, and are supposed to call [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) in the case there is a validation error.

The easier way to find if there are errors set for a form is to use `form_get_errors()`, which returns the array with all the errors set with `form_set_error()`, the function that is also called from `form_error()`.

In the case more than one node is validated, you would need to call `form_set_error(NULL, '', TRUE)` before `node_validate()`, and then get from `form_get_errors()` the array containing the error messages; if this is empty, there are no error messages.

```
form_set_error(NULL, '', TRUE);

// node_validate() call.

$errors = form_get_errors();

if (!empty($errors)) {
  // Some module reported an error.
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the following snippet to verify no module reported an error, after you call `node_validate()`:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['messages']['error'])) {
  // Some module reported an error.
}
```

Before calling `node_validate()` from the cron task, you would need to set `$_SESSION['messages']['error']` to an empty array; in that way, you are sure the errors reported in the array are caused by the node validation hooks.

`$_SESSION['messages']` is the variable used from [`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6) to store the messages passed to the function.

```
function drupal_set_message($message = NULL, $type = 'status', $repeat = TRUE) {
  if ($message) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
      $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['messages'][$type])) {
      $_SESSION['messages'][$type] = array();
    }
    // …
  }
  // …
}
```

Comment: is this work on drupal 7 ?

Comment: The question is for Drupal 6; you need to slightly change the code for Drupal 7.

Comment: can you just give a direction how to do in drupal 7